# How to add monochrome noise to a PyGame surface using NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, pygame

So far I've come up with following:

```
screen_array = pygame.surfarray.pixels2d(self.screen)
noise_small = numpy.random.random((self.width/4,self.height/4)) * 0.2 + 0.4
noise_big = noise_small .repeat(4, 0).repeat(4, 1)
screen_array *= noise_big
```

But this adds separate noise on every channel.

I know I could also use `pygame.surfarray.pixels3d` and then `numpy.tile` the noise array, but that's way too slow for me (well, what I'm doing now is also pretty slow, but nevermind that).

Comment: @JohnRiselvato I might simply not get it, but how is it related to my question..?

Comment: In other words greyscale, [wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monochrome)

Comment: I believe function name of `pygame.surfarray.pixels3d` implies it's about images and not sound...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each element in the array returned by `pygame.surfarray.pixels2d` is a number obtained by packing the 3 channels into a single integer, and I don't know of a simple method to take advantage of the array structure to do a fast and simple multiplication with this.

However, I still think your best bet is to use `pygame.surfarray.pixels3d`, but not to use `numpy.tile`. You could do something like this :

```py
    screen_array = pygame.surfarray.pixels3d(self.screen)
    noise_small = numpy.random.random((self.width/4,self.height/4)) * 0.2 + 0.4
    noise_big = noise_small .repeat(4, 0).repeat(4, 1)
    screen_array *= noise_big[:, :, numpy.newaxis]
```

Notice the `[:, :, numpy.newaxis]`. This reshape the `noise_big` to be of shape `(X, Y, 1)` instead of (X, Y), which allows direct multiplication with the `screen_array` object, having shape `(X, Y, 3)`. When that happens, the single element of the third axis is multiplied with all 3 channels. This way of tackling the problem is more efficient than using `numpy.tile`.